# How can I make multiple calls to initWithContentsOfURL without it eventually returning the wrong stuff?

Tags: macos, html-parsing, initwithcontentsofurl

I'm doing multiple levels of parsing of web pages where I use information from one page to drill down and grab a "lower" page to parse. When I get to the lowest level of my hierarchy, I no longer hit a new page, I basically hit the same one (with different parameters) and make SQL database entries.

If I don't slow things down (by putting a sleep(1)) before that inner loop, initWithContentsOfURL eventually returns a kind of stub piece of HTML. Here's the code I use to get my HTML nodes:

```
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSString* webStringURL = [sURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *contentData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: webStringURL] 
                                                         options: 0 
                                                           error: &err] autorelease];   
    NSString *dataString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData: contentData
                                                  encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] autorelease];    
    NSData *data = [dataString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    TFHpple *xPathDoc = [[[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData: data] autorelease];
```

It works fine with 4 levels of looping. In faxt, it can run 24/7 with no real memory leak problem. It only dies when I have a connection issue. That is as long as I put in the sleep(1) before the inner-most loop.

It's like it's too fast and initWithContentsOfURL can't keep up. I suppose I could try to do something asynchronous but this is not for user-consumption and the direct synchronous looping works just fine... almost. I've tried different ways of slowing things down. Pausing for one second on a regular basis works but if I take that out, it starts getting bogus data after about 10 times through the inner loop. Is there a way to handle this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a problem of `initWithContentsOfURL`; rather, I suspect it's the server or network that is unable to respond that quickly.

The following assumes that's the case.

If you want to receive network errors and/or server response errors, you need to use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There's no way to get notified about the error from `initWithContentsOfURL`. If you know what is the stub page, or if you know a magic string in the successful response, you can check the returned `NSData` against those.